# GGplot inside for loop, with a subset dataframe for each subject, multiplot (78 plots)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Basically I am trying to use a for loop to plot (26rows for 26 subjects, 3 cols for Breakfast(A), Lunch(B) and Dinner(C)) = 78 graphs of Blood Glucose Concentration against Timeline, with factors of 4 levels (1,2,3,4). The error that gets thrown out is:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Change`.
x `mt == 1 ~ mean_bgc - mean_bgc[mt == 1 & Timeline == 0]` must be length 39 or one, not 0.
i Input `Change` is `case_when(...)`.
I have a strong feeling that I shouldn't be mutating within the for loop, apologies as I am still relatively new to r. Anyway the idea is to create a new column named as `Change` by subtracting each baseline for each meal type at Timeline = 0, from the mean_bgc. The data is pretty complicated
Below here is a snippet of the data:

```
structure(list(Subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), Day = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14
), `Meal Type` = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", 
"MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), 
    Timeline = c(0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
    165, 180), `Meal Timings` = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), BGC = c(3.44, 
    3.5, 3.89, 5.33, 6.5, 7.17, 8.5, 9.28, 8.89, 8, 7.17, 6.17, 
    5.11, 4.28, 5.83, 8.39, 10.33, 11.44, 11.67, 10.5, 8.56, 
    7, 6.39, 6.17, 5.44, 4.5, 3.78, 4.17, 5.5, 7.5, 8.83, 8.94, 
    8.61, 8.39, 8.11, 7.39, 6.33, 5.06, 4.11, 3.39, 4.11, 7.06, 
    9.67, 10.44, 9.78, 8.61, 7.5, 7.11, 6.61, 6.22, 6.5, 6.39, 
    4.33, 5.28, 7.61, 9.28, 9.17, 8.39, 7.89, 7.56, 7.17, 6.67, 
    6.22, 5.56, 4.67, 4.28, 4.28, 4.22, 4.22, 4.17, 4.44, 5.89, 
    8, 8.61, 7.39, 6, 5.17, 4.56, 4.17, 4.06, 4.67, 6, 7.22, 
    7.94, 7.83, 6.72, 6.56, 6.83, 6.5, 5.89, 5.06, 4.22, 4.17, 
    4.39, 6.17, 8.89, 10.94, 11.78, 11.56, 10.78, 9.94, 9, 7.83, 
    6.61, 4.06, 4.44, 5.56, 6.94, 7.78, 7.72, 7.56, 7.22, 7.11, 
    7.61, 7.89, 8.28, 8.83, 4.39, 4.5, 5.56, 7.5, 8.28, 7.72, 
    6.5, 5.89, 6.61, 7.39, 6.78, 5.44, 5, 4.06, 4.61, 5.28, 4.78, 
    3.72, 3.61, 4.39, 4.72, 5.44, 6.83, 7.17, 6.39, 5.83, 5.83, 
    5.89, 6.33, 7.28, 7, 5.33, 4.39, 4.78, 5.28, 5.17, 4.78, 
    4.83, 5.22, 4.39, 4.72, 5.22, 5.44, 4.61, 4.11, 5.33, 6.67, 
    6.72, 6.5, 6.33, 6.06, 5.56, 4, 4, 4.94, 6.33, 6.11, 4.5, 
    3.67, 3.67, 4.78, 5.28, 4.56, 3.72, 4, 4.06, 4.33, 5.72, 
    6.56, 5.83, 4.89, 4.72, 4.72, 4.5, 4.61, 5.22, 5.56, 5.33, 
    4.5, 4.78, 5.61, 6.44, 6.28, 5.94, 6.61, 7.72, 8.06, 7.72, 
    7.11, 5.94, 5.11, 3.61, 3.89, 4.44, 5.39, 5.72, 5.39, 5.17, 
    5.11, 4.94, 4.61, 4.39, 4.22, 4.17, 3.78, 4.56, 7.22, 8.61, 
    7.78, 6.11, 5.17, 5.11, 5.83, 6.44, 6.22, 6, 6.06, 4.56, 
    5.17, 7.33, 9.11, 8.94, 7.83, 6.67, 6.06, 6.22, 6.61, 6.94, 
    6.78, 6.28, 3.83, 4.22, 5, 5.33, 5.11, 5.06, 5.39, 6.11, 
    6.78, 6.28, 5.44, 5.56, 5.78, 5.56, 7.67, 9.17, 8.83, 7.94, 
    7.44, 6.89, 6.11, 5.83, 5.61, 4.94, 5.06, 5.28, 5.06, 4.94, 
    5.56, 6.22, 6.28, 6.33, 6.61, 6.44, 5.89, 5.11, 4.78, 5.28, 
    5.61, 3.89, 4.28, 5.17, 5.67, 5.22, 4.67, 4.28, 4.56, 5.11, 
    5.06, 4.89, 4.83, 4.67, 4, 4.22, 5.11, 6.56, 6.94, 6.78, 
    7.17, 7.56, 7.39, 7.39, 7.44, 6.39, 4.67, 4.28, 4.39, 4.89, 
    4.89, 4.44, 4.33, 4.56, 4.78, 4.78, 5.11, 5.78, 6.17, 6.06, 
    3.83, 4.28, 5, 4.56, 3.67, 3.5, 4.22, 5.33, 5.89, 5.72, 5.22, 
    5.22, 5.33, 3.89, 4.78, 6.78, 7.39, 6.5, 5.56, 5.17, 5.33, 
    5.33, 4.89, 4.72, 4.89, 4.44, 6.22, 6.22, 6.17, 6.22, 5.72, 
    4.94, 4.56, 4.83, 5.06, 5.06, 4.61, 4.28, 4.56, 3.56, 3.94, 
    5.33, 6.33, 6.44, 6.11, 5.89, 5.72, 5.33, 4.56, 3.89, 3.72, 
    4, 4, 5.06, 7.11, 8.22, 7.28, 6.39, 6.11, 6.28, 6.22, 5.78, 
    5.11, 5.06, 5.5, 4.06, 4.78, 6.28, 7, 6.22, 5.39, 5.39, 5.94, 
    6.06, 5.78, 5.17, 4.67, 4.44, 3.72, 4.33, 4.89, 4.39, 3.72, 
    3.5, 3.5, 3.83, 4.39, 4.56, 3.94, 3.89, 4.28, 4.83, 5.39, 
    5.89, 5.78, 5.67, 5.89, 5.61, 5, 4.89, 5.33, 5.44, 4.61, 
    4.06, 4.06, 4.44, 5.83, 6.89, 6.61, 5.83, 5.22, 4.83, 4.83, 
    5.06, 5.17, 5.11, 4.94, 3.39, 3.5, 4.28, 5.17, 5.22, 4.78, 
    4.5, 4.67, 5.06, 5.11, 4.94, 4.72, 4.28, 3.5, 3.83, 5.44, 
    7, 6.89, 5.61, 4.33, 4, 4.44, 4.67, 4.39, 4.28, 4.5, 4.22, 
    5.89, 7.33, 6.83, 5.5, 4.44, 4.17, 4.39, 4.33, 4.28, 4.28, 
    4.33, 4.5, 3.72, 4.44, 5.56, 5.83, 5.06, 4.33, 4.28, 4.33, 
    4.33, 4.17, 4, 3.61, 3.39, 3.83, 5.44, 7.78, 8.67, 8.44, 
    7.83, 6.83, 6, 5.94, 6.28, 6.06, 5.39, 4.94, 3.61, 4.33, 
    5.94, 6.44, 5.72, 4.89, 4.33, 4.17, 4.33, 4.5, 4.39, 4.17, 
    3.78)), row.names = c(NA, -520L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Along with an example of what I have tried

```
for (i in min(df1$Subject):max(df1$Subject)) {
  k1 = subset(df1, df1$Subject == i)
  k2 = aggregate(k1$BGC, by=list(Timeline=k1$Timeline, mt = k1$`Meal Type`, motd = k1$`Meal Timings`), FUN=mean) %>% rename(mean_bgc = x) %>% subset(mt != "MMTT")
  k2 %>% filter(motd == "A") -> k2A
  k2 %>% filter(motd == "B") -> k2B
  k2 %>% filter(motd == "C") -> k2C
  abs1 = k2A %>% mutate(Change = case_when(`mt` == 1 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==1 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 2 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt`==2 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 3 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==3 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 4 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==4 & `Timeline` == 0], TRUE~NA_real_)) %>% subset(Timeline!= -30 & Timeline!=-15) %>% mutate(Change = round(abs(Change), 2))
#Lunch
  abs2 = k2B %>% mutate(Change = case_when(`mt` == 1 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==1 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 2 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt`==2 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 3 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==3 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 4 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==4 & `Timeline` == 0], TRUE~NA_real_)) %>% subset(Timeline!= -30 & Timeline!=-15) %>% mutate(Change = round(abs(Change), 2))
#Dinner
  abs3 = k2C %>% mutate(Change = case_when(`mt` == 1 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==1 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 2 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt`==2 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 3 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==3 & `Timeline` == 0], `mt` == 4 ~ `mean_bgc` - `mean_bgc`[`mt` ==4 & `Timeline` == 0], TRUE~NA_real_)) %>% subset(Timeline!= -30 & Timeline!=-15) %>% mutate(Change = round(abs(Change), 2))
ga = ggplot(abs1, aes(x = Timeline, y = Change)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = `mt`, linetype = `mt`)) + ggtitle(paste(subject_name, "Incremental Change BGC"))
gb = ggplot(abs2, aes(x = Timeline, y = Change)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = `mt`, linetype = `mt`)) + ggtitle(paste(subject_name, "Incremental Change BGC"))
gc = ggplot(abs3, aes(x = Timeline, y = Change)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = `mt`, linetype = `mt`)) + ggtitle(paste(subject_name, "Incremental Change BGC"))
gx <- ggarrange(ga,gb,gc,labels = c("A", "B", "C"), ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
print(gx)
}
```

**EDIT** I found out that for certain subjects, like the one below here, does not have `mt = 1` I was wondering if there is a way to skip this in the `case_when` section? Here's an example of a subject without `mt=1`

````
structure(list(Subject = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), Day = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14
), `Meal Type` = c("MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", 
"MMTT", "MMTT", "MMTT", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2"), Timeline = c(60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 
135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 
150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 
180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 
0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 
30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 
45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 
60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 
90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 
105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 
120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 
135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 
150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 
165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 
180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 
0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 
30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 
45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 
60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 
75, 90, 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180), `Meal Timings` = c("A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), BGC = c(6.28, 6.56, 
6.28, 5.89, 5.56, 4.94, 4.33, 4.06, 4.28, 2.94, 3.11, 4.39, 6.11, 
7.17, 7.5, 7.28, 6.44, 6.17, 6.5, 6, 4.67, 3.83, 3.67, 4.06, 
4.78, 5.22, 5.17, 4.83, 4.61, 4.78, 4.61, 4.22, 4.5, 4.83, 4.39, 
3.56, 3.94, 4.5, 4.67, 4.89, 5.11, 4.61, 4.11, 4.39, 5.33, 5.72, 
5, 4.61, 4.17, 5.17, 4.67, 3.78, 4.72, 5.94, 5.28, 4, 4.17, 5.22, 
5.33, 4.78, 4.17, 4.06, 4.28, 4.67, 4.89, 4.67, 4, 3.72, 4.28, 
4.67, 4.94, 5.28, 5.17, 4.83, 3.61, 3.72, 4.33, 5.17, 4.83, 4.17, 
4.39, 4.72, 4.67, 4.5, 4.17, 4.11, 4.11, 4.17, 4.44, 4.39, 4.39, 
4.17, 4.5, 4.33, 3.67, 3.83, 4.22, 3.94, 3.72, 3.67, 3.56, 3.61, 
4.22, 4.72, 4.56, 4.44, 4.56, 4.39, 4.28, 4.39, 4.28, 4.33, 4.61, 
4.17, 4.39, 4.72, 4.72, 4.44, 4.11, 4.39, 4.83, 4.83, 4.56, 4.56, 
4.67, 5.06, 2.44, 2.22, 2.44, 2.89, 2.56, 2.39, 2.22, 2.22, 2.22, 
2.22, 2.22, 2.94, 2.78, 3, 2.89, 3.33, 4.22, 4.06, 4, 4.44, 4.94, 
5.17, 5.06, 4.89, 4.83, 4.44, 3.44, 3.78, 4.17, 4.5, 4.67, 4.44, 
4.44, 4.61, 4.56, 4.33, 4.11, 4.28, 4.17, 3.33, 3.06, 2.72, 3.94, 
6.22, 6.72, 6.39, 5.72, 5.06, 4.89, 5.17, 5.11, 4.78, 3.22, 3.28, 
3.56, 4.11, 4.72, 4.61, 4.28, 4.5, 5.11, 5.17, 4.11, 3.83, 4.5, 
3.78, 4, 4.11, 4.17, 4.56, 4.33, 3.94, 3.94, 4.17, 4.39, 4.06, 
3.61, 3.94, 3.83, 4, 4.67, 5.39, 5.17, 4.5, 4.06, 4.17, 4.5, 
4.67, 4.72, 4.78, 5.22, 3.67, 3.78, 3.89, 3.89, 4, 4.33, 4.72, 
4.78, 4.44, 4.06, 3.89, 4.06, 4.17, 4.11, 4.33, 4.61, 4.5, 4.33, 
4.44, 4.61, 4.61, 4.72, 4.89, 4.67, 4.56, 5.06, 3.94, 4.5, 4.78, 
4.61, 4.39, 4.33, 4.44, 5.06, 5.28, 4.72, 4.56, 4.33, 3.78, 3.94, 
3.94, 4.17, 4.44, 4.61, 5, 4.89, 3.94, 4, 4.78, 5.17, 5, 4.28, 
3.61, 3.5, 4.17, 4.78, 5.56, 6.06, 5.72, 5.06, 4.78, 4.61, 4.28, 
4.28, 4.83, 3.89, 3.89, 4.22, 4.44, 5.22, 6.11, 5.56, 4.5, 4.44, 
5.11, 5.39, 5.06, 4.28)), row.names = c(NA, -295L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))```
````

Comment: Your code `subset` result `abs1` is an empty df so it will cause error next line. Please check again :)

Comment: @SinhNguyen when I tried doing manually to firstly subset to one subject, my code works, but when i do it in a loop the code no longer works

Comment: You can check what is the value of the `i` after the loop failed. Than run the code inside the loop with that i value

Comment: @SinhNguyen how do I go about tracing the `i` where the loop failed? So sorry ><

Comment: @SinhNguyen in the case for some subjects who do not have `mt =1` to begin with, is it possible to bypass/ignore in the `case_when`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue arises from `mean_bgc[mt == 1 & Timeline == 0]`. The `&` operator uses the `Timeline` vector instead of `Timeline == 0`. When using `mean_bgc[mt ==1 & (Timeline == 0)]` (including the backticks as above), it worked for me (I dropped `subject_name` though).

Comment: I tried, that's not the issue, I found out that the premise is that for some subjects they dont have `mt ==1` to begin with, which the code fails. Otherwise, subjects with `mt=1` could easily pass the for loop

Answer (score 0):

I switched `case_when` to `if_else`, and the codes work now! `k2$Change <- NA k2 %>% mutate(Change = ifelse(k2$mt==1 & k2$motd=='A',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==1 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='A'], ifelse(k2$mt==2 & k2$motd=='A',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==2 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='A'],ifelse(k2$mt==3 & k2$motd=='A',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==3 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='A'],ifelse(k2$mt==4 & k2$motd=='A',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==4 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='A'],ifelse(k2$mt==1 & k2$motd=='B',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==1 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='B'], ifelse(k2$mt==2 & k2$motd=='B',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==2 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='B'],ifelse(k2$mt==3 & k2$motd=='B',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==3 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='B'],ifelse(k2$mt==4 & k2$motd=='B',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==4 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='B'],ifelse(k2$mt==1 & k2$motd=='C',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==1 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='C'], ifelse(k2$mt==2 & k2$motd=='C',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==2 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='C'],ifelse(k2$mt==3 & k2$motd=='C',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==3 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='C'],ifelse(k2$mt==4 & k2$motd=='C',`mean_bgc`-`mean_bgc`[`mt `==4 & (`Timeline`== 0) &`motd`=='C'],NA))))))))))))) -> k2`